# Is there a non-graphical rover simulation node?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a simple node that subscribes to cmd_vel and publishes reasonable (for a rover) Pose and Twist messages?  Something like turtlesim but with real Pose messages and no GUI.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402029/is-there-a-non-graphical-rover-simulation-node?/) by [kylerlaird](https://answers.ros.org/users/23170/kylerlaird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2022-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros_control` has an `open_loop` parameter. That takes the cmd_vel messages and uses that to calculate the odometry (instead of using encoder data). Is that what you're looking for?

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1